# ConstraintLayout Sizing Issue

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm having an issue sizing children in a `ConstraintLayout`. I have 3 views:

- `TextView` (`item_quantity`): I want this to grow indefinitely, but not push the `TextInputLayout` off the screen
- `TextInputLayout` (`data_entry_layout`): I want this to fill all available horizontal space and have a minimum width of `120dp` no matter what
- `ImageView` (`camera_scan`): This will not grow, just needs to not get pushed off the screen

If `item_quantity` has short text, I want it to look like the image below. I want `data_entry_layout` to fill all available space.

[image: short text version]

If `item_quantity` has long text, I want it to fill and grow but I want the `data_entry_layout` to never be smaller than `120dp`. I want it to honor the `minWidth`. So, I want it to look like this:

[image: long text version]

Here is my current configuration:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_quantity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/data_entry_layout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:text="90,000 Boxes of Stuff Are Needed"
        android:textColor="@color/color_on_background"
        android:textSize="@dimen/workflow_item_view_item_quantity_text_size" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_entry_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/camera_scan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/item_quantity"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        android:contentDescription="@string/disable_realwear_asr"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        app:errorIconDrawable="@null">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/data_entry"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_instruction_data_entry_text_size"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_scan"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/data_entry_layout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/data_entry_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_selector"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/qrcode_scan"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription,KeyboardInaccessibleWidget" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If I set `item_quantity`'s `layout_width` to `0dp` then the UI works with lots of text, but takes up too much horizontal space with short text:

[image: 0dp looks bad with short text]

If I set `item_quantity`'s `layout_width` to `wrap_content` then the UI works with short text, but pushes the `data_entry_layout` off the screen with large text:

[image: wrap_content looks bad with long text]

I must be missing something simple. Is there a way I can get both of these situations to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the `android:minWidth` property try using `app:layout_constraintWidth_min`. ConstraintLayout seems to either ignore or overrule certain properties with the "android" namespace when it comes to sizing of elements.

Comment: This worked! I did not realize `ConstraintLayout` had its own min width property. Thank you!